# is it possible to install ESXi on linux?

Tags: centos5, esxi

ESXi installs on a physical machine separately. I mean it's not a software which installs on an OS like a Linux machine. Am I right?
I need something like ESXi server to be installed on a CentOS 5 physical machine.
What's your suggestion?

Comment: My suggestion: ask on ServerFault; this isn't a programming Q.

Comment: see here http://www.thegeekstuff.com/2010/06/vmware-esxi-installation-guide/

Comment: Normally you install ESXi directly on bare hardware, but it is possible to run a "nested" instance inside a VMware Workstation VM (e.g. for development purposes). See http://kb.vmware.com/selfservice/microsites/search.do?language=en_US&cmd=displayKC&externalId=2009916

Answer (score 4, accepted):

ESXi is a Hypervisor which installs directly onto hardware. Its almost like a mini OS if you like, so you can't install that on Linux. Software which will provide virtualization on top on the OS will be the likes of KVM, Xen or VirtualBox which would be better suited for you (sounds like it anyway)

Have a look at [this link](http://www.cyberciti.biz/tips/linux-virtualization-software.html)

Comment: thanx for your complete answer. see, the server resides somewhere on the net. it has a valid ip and centos 5 is installed on it. i want to be able to experience an environment like when it would be an X server and i would be connecting to it as a terminal and may work in a graphical OS.

Comment: This is not really true. Nested ESXi instances (in e.g. VMware Workstation VMs) are also possible.

Comment: Sorry Andrew, but he was asking about ESXi specifically, and [vSphere ESXi is a bare-metal / Type 1 hypervisor](http://www.vmware.com/products/esxi-and-esx/overview), whereas what you are talking about is a [Type-2 hypervisor](http://searchservervirtualization.techtarget.com/definition/hosted-hypervisor-Type-2-hypervisor), which is why I mentioned the other options.